# Error trying to connect to a sharepoint site using CSOM with .Net Standard

Tags: csom

I'm trying to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard

The user is my Office 365 account that has MFA enabled so I have created an app password account

[image]

But when I try the code I get this error

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the content of result property? What's the structure? Also check the status code of the response. Maybe it returns some error. If API call returns any error then there is no access_token property.

Comment: At the moment of the error result has nothing

Comment: ok. Please share the content of result property

Comment: This is what I see on quick inspection:Local variables and arguments are not available in '[Exception]' call stack frames. To get them, set the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown and rerun the scenario. string

Comment: Set the breakpoint on the line `var tokenResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(result);` then you should be able to inspect result `property`